# can I automtically catch the potential exceptions in an android studio project?

Tags: android, exception, android-studio

Does Android studio provides a tool to catch potential (unhandled) exceptions in an android studio project ? I want to run it on my whole project rather than going manually to each individual source file !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can analyze your code with **Android Lint**, which does the static code analysis.

Right click on your root **Project folder** -> **Analyze** -> **Inspect code**.

You can configure what Android Lint searches/reports for in the Settings.

More information about Android Lint can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/help/lint.html).

> The Android lint tool is a static code analysis tool that checks your
>   Android project source files for potential bugs and optimization
>   improvements for correctness, security, performance, usability,
>   accessibility, and internationalization.